# Flutter FIrebase trying to add users to the users list but it is not appending the list, the list has only the newly added value

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I was trying to add users to the users list but it is not appending the list, the list has only the newly added value.
I cant find what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code

```
sendToChatroom({String chatRoomId}) {
List<dynamic> users = List();

databaseMethods.getMap(chatRoomId).then((value) async {
  users = await value.data()['users'];
  print(users);
});
if (!users.contains(Constants.myName)) {
  users = users + [Constants.myName];
  print(users);
}

Map<String, dynamic> chatRoomMap = {
  "users": users,
  "chatRoomId": chatRoomId
};
databaseMethods.setMap(chatRoomId, chatRoomMap);
Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GroupChat(chatRoomId)));
}
```

Database methods

```
getMap(String groupChatName) async {
return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("groupChat")
    .doc(groupChatName)
    .get();
}

setMap(String groupChatName, Map groupChatMap) async {
return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("groupChat")
    .doc(groupChatName)
    .set(groupChatMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append the array, you should use `FieldValue.arrayUnion`

Example:

```
Map<String, dynamic> chatRoomMap = {
  "users": FieldValue.arrayUnion(users),
  "chatRoomId": chatRoomId
};
```

With this, `users` would be appended to the current array value.